# Comapring Two Arrays in Perl For Same Values

Tags: perl-module

Lets say i have two arrays

```
@array1 holds the below values

branches/test1/a.txt
branches/test2/b.txt
branches/test2/c.txt

and 

@array2 

branches/test1/a.txt
branches/test2/b.txt
branches/test2/c.txt
```

I need to Compare both the arrays and do something if it matches.

I find Array::Compare is has too much dependencies to be installed. Any alternative ways for this ?

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to compare two arrays?

In which case two arrays are equal:

**1. Elements in both arrays are same**

**2. Elements in both arrays are same and there order is also same**

Comment: Elements in both arrays are same and there order is also same